# Fadeout validation error messages in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, checkout

When placing an order, WooCommerce does validate all required user fields inputs. If not, the checkout-errors messages appear like if  the first name is missing and so on.

I want those error validation messages to fade out after a given time.

So, I injected this jQuery code:

```
(function($) {
    var wooError = $('.woocommerce-error'); 
    wooError.delay(4000).fadeOut(160);
})
(jQuery);
```

As long the `.woocommerce-error` class is not within `form.checkout`, it works fine, like on login or register for example. But it does not work on checkout page.

The class `.woocommerce-error` is correct *(it's there)*, but the fadeOut isn't triggered.

So, I went on searching the web. Found an other approach, to wait for `checkout_error` checkout page event, like so:

```
$( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
    var wooError = $('.woocommerce-error'); 
    wooError.delay(4000).fadeOut(160);
})
(jQuery);
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me, why I can not trigger the `.woocommerce-error` class to fadeout as long it's inside the checkout form?

How to trigger the fadeOut on checkout error validation messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code using `setTimeout()` instead of `delay()`, that will fade out any error message on checkout page with a delay of 4 seconds and a duration of 160 mili-seconds:

```
// Checkout JS
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_fadeout_error_message');
function checkout_fadeout_error_message() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document.body).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
            var wooError = $('.woocommerce-error');
            setTimeout(function(){
                wooError.fadeOut(160);
            }, 4000);
        })
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you mate. I will give it a shot. Looks more comfortable than my approaching.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the way. If there's someone else looking for this, here's how it works:

```
(function($) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
        var wooError = $('.woocommerce-error'); 
        wooError.delay(4000).fadeOut(160);
    })
})   
(jQuery);
```

After 13 hours of coding and stuff you don't see the obvious sometimes.